# Push a RingCentral app to production (fax)

Tags: ringcentral

I have a fax app and I am able to hit the API. I have been trying to move it to production. I have bought an Office Premium account and put in my new main line, but received no word from the developer team.

Also, regarding the requirement for an app to be moved to production, I have met all the requirements except `5+ API calls per each used endpoint (20+ in total)`.

Does anyone know to successfully push a RingCentral app to production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make at least 20 API calls in total and 5 per endpoint, for instance, if you have only two permissions, along with making 5 calls per API endpoint (with that permission), you need to make 10 more API calls to hit the 20 API calls mark. Once the requirement is met you should be able to move your app to production.

Here are the steps to move your app to production.
https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/basics/production

If you still have issues, please submit a ticket with your client id
https://support.ringcentral.com/contact-support.html

Answer (score 3):

Please make more Fax API (20 at least ) calls on this app and give it at least 4 hours for the new API calls to reflect on the analytics. Once all the graduation requirements are satisfied, "Apply for Production" button is activated.

If you still have issues, please open a case with RingCentral Developer Support at developers.ringcentral.com and request your app graduation by providing the Client ID.

Comment: Also the official guidelines just FYI: https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/basics/production